# How to make an function call in node js like java method which will return a variable after computing

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, sails.js

I am new to NodeJS and from sycnronous world of JAVA.I am trying to achieve calling of multiple rest api's using restler based on input array in node js/ sails js.
But I am not able to store the data in array variable (result) because it is asynchronous call. I tried to work on callback still couldn't achieve same. Any thoughts.

```
getSomething: function(req, res) {
    var result = [];
    var queryCode = ["a", "b", "c"];
    for (var i = 0; i < queryCode; i++) {
        {
            callDB(url, queryCode, function(data) {
                result.push(data); // this result is specific to the this function
            });
        }
        res.ok(result); //this result is not affected with the above push.
        // Since I can only send res.ok() once I can't put this inside for-loop.
    } // end of getSomething
    function callDB(url, queryCode, callback) {

        restler.postJson(url, queryCode).once('complete', function(resultdata, response) {
            //some template
            var queryResult = transform(resultdata, template);
            return callback(queryResult);

        });
    };
```

Comment: Have a look at any asynchronous library to keep you from reinventing the wheel. For instance: https://github.com/caolan/async#forEachOf

Comment: try using ajax function with "async" set to false.

jQuery.ajax({
        url: url+ queryCode,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
           var queryResult = transform(resultdata, template);
            return callback(queryResult);
        },
        async: false
    });